# Bus Refresh Endpoint not working in spring cloud Finchley.M8

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-bus

Im using Spring cloud config Finchley.M8 version with Spring boot 2.0.0.RELEASE.
I have noticed the /bus/refresh has been changed to /bus-refresh.
But whenever I hit the url using post http request, it is not working.
Here is a snippet of the application.properties:

```
spring.cloud.bus.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=bus-refresh,refresh
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
```

Also, I extended the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to add the following code snippet:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).permitAll();
}
```

And this is the url am trying to test with:

```
post http://localhost:8000/bus-refresh?destination=**:dev
```

Then I got the following error message

```
{
"timestamp": "2018-03-18T07:03:54.135+0000",
"status": 403,
"error": "Forbidden",
"message": "Forbidden",
"path": "/bus-refresh"
}
```

Also, here a snippet from the dependencies in pom.xml:

```
    <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.M8</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-monitor</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
        <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Any help please?

> Note: I was using older version of spring cloud with spring 1.5.6 and it was working fine, I faced this problem when I migrated to Spring boot 2 with the newest spring cloud version.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution for my problem, it is about security.
Simply I modified the configure method in my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with additional two lines. It would be like the following snippet:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).permitAll();
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.httpBasic().disable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to fix your issue:

```
spring-boot 2.0.1.RELEASE
spring-cloud-bus 2.0.0.RC1

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: bus-refresh,refresh

      base-path: /
```